# API get call returns status 400

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mern

I'm trying to learn how to use the MERN stack. I've been following a YouTube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WT67-OETeGU). Currently, I've defined and created my server.js file as follows:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const todoRoutes = express.Router();
const PORT = 4000;

let Todo = require("./todo.model.js");

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/todos", {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true
});

const connection = mongoose.connection;

todoRoutes.route("/").get(function(req, res) {
  Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error getting data");
    } else {
      res.json(todos);
    }
  });
});

todoRoutes.route("/:id").get(function(req, res) {
  let id = req.params.id;
  Todo.findById(id, function(err, todo) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error finding todo object with id: " + id);
    } else {
      res.json(todo);
    }
  });
});

todoRoutes.route("/add").post(function(req, res) {
  let todo = new Todo(req.body);
  todo
    .save()
    .then(todo => {
      res.status(200).json({ todo: "Todo added successfully" });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send("failed to save new todo");
    });
});

todoRoutes.route("/update/:id").post(function(req, res) {
  let id = req.params.id;
  Todo.findById(id, function(err, todo) {
    if (!todo) {
      res.status(400).send("cant update id: " + id);
    } else {
      todo.todo_description = req.body.todo_description;
      todo.todo_responsible = req.body.todo_responsible;
      todo.todo_priority = req.body.todo_priority;
      todo.todo_completed = req.body.todo_completed;
      todo
        .save()
        .then(todo => {
          res.json("Todo updated");
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(400).send("update not possible"));
    }
  });
});

app.use("./todos", todoRoutes);
```

I am trying to test my API out, so I installed Postman and set it up. I'm trying to make a GET request to: http://localhost:4000/todos. However, Postman only returns a 404, saying "Could not get any response".

I've run the commands mongod and mongo on my terminal to get Mongo running.

Any suggestions on where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any messages in the console after launching express or after requesting with postman? Did you check if you are performing a GET request?

Comment: No messages appear on my console, other than "starting node server.js". Yes, double checked on Postman.

Comment: Please make sure that you're sending id in GET API request....
Could you please help me to know the complete API path which you're testing on Postman?
Also, please confirm what is the exact returned status code & error message.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are setting your endpoints as relative paths. Can you remove the dot proceeding "/todos"? in `app.use("./todos", todoRoutes);`
`